# URLComponent percentEncodedPath - Is value valid before setting it

Tags: swift, url, urlencode

Trying to pass a `string` to URLComponents's `percentEncodedPath` crashes the app if the string is not a valid percent encoded path.

Is there a way to tell if the string is a valid percent encoded path before I set it? I am having trouble figuring this one out.

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.percentEncodedPath = "/some failing path/" // <- This crashes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
extension String {
    
    var isPercentEncoded: Bool {
        
        let decoded = self.removingPercentEncoding
        return decoded != nil && decoded != self
    }
}
```

The rationale:

- If the String is URL-encoded, `removingPercentEncoding` will decode it, and hence `decoded` will be different from `self`
- If the String contains a percent (but is not URL-Encoded), `removingPercentEncoding` will fail, and hence `decoded` will be `nil`
- Otherwise string will remain unmodified

Example:

```
let failingPath = "/some failing path/"
let succeedingPath = "%2Fsome+succeeding+path%2F"
let doubleEncoded = "%252Fsome%2Bfailing%2Bpath%252F"
let withPercent = "a%b"

failingPath.isPercentEncoded // returns false
succeedingPath.isPercentEncoded // returns true
doubleEncoded.isPercentEncoded // returns true
withPercent.isPercentEncoded // returns false
```

One disadvantage is that you are on a mercy of `removingPercentEncoding` and also this is a "mechanical" interpretation of the string, which may not take into account the implementation intent. For example `a%20b` will be interpreted as URL-encoded. But what if your app expects that string as a decoded one (and so it needs to be encoded further)?